# TYPO3 10 Viewhelper class not found, Fluid error

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, view-helpers, typo3-10.x

There is some **small** detail I seem to be missing but I just can't find out what it is...

I get this error:

```
Error: The ViewHelper "<ugh:example>" could not be resolved. Based on your spelling, the system would load the class "TYPO3\Projectname\ViewHelpers\ExampleViewHelper", however this class does not exist.
```

I have my own extension called `sitepackage`, which works without issues.

In my `ext_localconf.php` I wrote

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['fluid']['namespaces']['ugh'] = ['TYPO3\\Projectname\\ViewHelpers'];
```

Then there's the directory `ViewHelpers` inside `Classes` with the file `ExampleViewHelper.php`

```
<?php

namespace TYPO3\Projectname\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

// etc ...
```

I expect it to use like `<ugh:example />`

What am I missing? Is there something outside of this that I have to do?
I'm freaking out about this...

Comment: I think too this is a caching / autoloading problem. Did you deactivate an re-activate your extension in backend of TYPO3?

Comment: Turns out it was an autoloading issue, Jonas solved it in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global configuration works, yet PHP is not able to find your `TYPO3\Projectname\ViewHelpers\ExampleViewHelper`.

I suspect that you have a spelling error or your autoloading information is out of date (assuming a composer-based installation, `composer dump-autoload` updates it) or you forgot to add your namespace to `composer.json` (see [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) or [a TYPO3 extension example here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/4-FirstExtension/2-create-folder-structure-and-configuration-files.html?highlight=psr-4)).

That said, the usual approach is to add ViewHelper namespaces to the Fluid template directly. See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html#importing-namespaces

**Without composer**

Use TYPO3 InstallTool "rebuild autoload information" or similar to build the class autoloading information. I think ext_emconf.php needs to contain the autoloading information, too.

Comment: The installation is actually not composer-based. Is there a disadvantag to the global namespace approach? I just see it as more convenient. Anyways, I tried the local namespace and it caused the same error.
Based on my post, do you see a spelling error? I really don't see one.

Comment: Without composer, use TYPO3 InstallTool "rebuild autoload information" or similar to build the class autoloading information. I think ext_emconf.php needs to have the autoloading information. + I had spelling errors so often...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I forgot that ext_emconf had autoload information! I updated my information in there, rebuilt autoload and then it worked, finally! 

Can I just mark your answer as the one that solved it or do you have to update your original answer?

Comment: Great! I'll put it up as answer so you can accept it.